# Insert join SQL Server from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to insert a record in my `RDV` table.

There is the query creation of my table `RDV`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RDV] 
(
    [idRdv]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [objet]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [objectif]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DateRdv]     DATETIME      NULL,
    [commentaire] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [archive]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [idClient]    INT           NULL,
    [idUser]      INT           NULL,
    [idResultat]  INT           NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RDV] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idRdv] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([idClient]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([idClient]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([idUser]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([idUser]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([idResultat]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Resultat] ([idResultat]
)
```

And below there is my code to insert in `RDV` table:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV(idUser, idClient, objet, objectif, DateRdv, commentaire) select (@idUser, @idClient, @objet, @objectif, @DateRdv, @commentaire) from RDV Client User where RDV.idClient = idClient.Client and RDV.idUser = User.idUser ";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YOSRA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=timar;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idClient", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objet", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectif", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRdv", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commentaire", textBox4.Text);

    con.Open();
    int LA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Ligne ajoutée: {0}", LA);
}
```

But it show me an error:

> Incorrect Syntax near ','

I can't understand what is wrong here?

Please help me.

Comment: is these values `@idUser,@idClient,@objet ... ` are column names?

Comment: @un-lucky Yes , there are

Comment: Yes definitely some syntax errors in there.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to insert an RDV but there is some Join , how can I wrote my query here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) select (@idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire) from RDV Client User where RDV.idClient=idClient.Client and RDV.idUser=User.idUser ";
```

Many issues in the above line.

1. Missing comma in between the tables `RDV Client User`, it should be `RDV, Client, User`
2. `idClient.Client` there is no table as `idClient`, it should be `Client.idClient`
3. `User` is a reserved keyword, use with `[]`, it should be `[User]`
4. Avoid `(`, `)` in the `SELECT` block, that causes the **Incorrect Syntax to ','** error.

So your code will be :

```
string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV (idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) select @idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire from RDV, Client, [User] where RDV.idClient = Client.idClient and RDV.idUser = [User].idUser ";
```

---

**Update:**

The above same code can be written with JOIN as follow:

```
string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO RDV (idUser, idClient, objet, objectif, DateRdv, commentaire) " +
                "SELECT @idUser, @idClient, @objet, @objectif, @DateRdv, @commentaire " +
                "FROM RDV R " +
                "JOIN Client C ON C.idClient = R.idClient " +
                "JOIN [User] U ON U.idUser = R.idUser ";
```

Answer (score 1):

missing a comma :

```
from RDV,Client,User
```

And use : `Client.idClient` instead of  `idClient.Client`

Your query must be :

```
string cmdStr = "Insert into RDV(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) select (@idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire) from RDV,Client,User where RDV.idClient=Client.idClient and RDV.idUser=User.idUser ";
```

But you have

> idRdv as Primary key

and he was not provided ,so you can not insert this row .

Comment: No copy and past the query in my answer i have edit it

Comment: What is the Error now ?

Comment: It's the same "INCORRECT SYNTAX TO ',' "

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert command in this way . Do not use a comma between the tables because it is old syntax

```
   Insert into RDV(idUser,idClient,objet,objectif,DateRdv,commentaire) 
   select 
   (@idUser,@idClient,@objet,@objectif,@DateRdv,@commentaire) 
   from RDV AS r
   inner join Client AS c ON r.idClient = c.ClientId
   inner join [User] AS u ON r.idUser = u.idUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `RDV Client User` is a table name.., So please try your query with `[RDV Client User]` 
Thanks